# Magento : Nested if else and conditional Statements in Email template

Tags: php, email, magento

i have a situation like this.

**Logic in PHP**

```
<?php $shippingcountry = $order->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId();
      // $order->getExtraAmount()  by default this value is 0.00
      if($order->getExtraAmount() > 0){
          // My 1st text message will be here. Ex : Hi
      }
      else {
         if($shippingcountry == 'US' || $shippingcountry == 'HK' || $shippingcountry == 'GB'){
              // My 2nd  text message will be here. Ex : Hi1
         }else{
              // My 3rd  text message will be here. Ex : Hi2
         }
     }
?>
```

This is my logic in php.

I wants implement the same logic inside transactional email for New Order Create Email.

```
{{if order.extra_amount > 0}}
      <p><h2>Hi</h2></p>
{{else}}
   {{depend order.getShippingAddress().country_id == 'US' || order.getShippingAddress().country_id == 'HK' || order.getShippingAddress().country_id == 'GB'}}
     <p><h2>Hi1</h2></p>
   {{/depend}}

   {{depend order.getShippingAddress().country_id != 'US' && order.getShippingAddress().country_id != 'HK' && order.getShippingAddress().country_id != 'GB'}}
        <p><h2>Hi2</h2></p>
   {{/depend}}
{{/if}}
```

How do i implement this logic in Order Create Email Template.

**Output : Hi**

In all the case.

and i tried these all ways

```
{{if order.extra_amount > 0}}
{{if order.extra_amount gt 0}}
{{if order.extra_amount == 0}}
{{if order.extra_amount != 0}}
{{if order.extra_amount eq 0}}
{{if order.extra_amount neq 0}}
```

Any ideas ???

thanks for your help.

Comment: May be easier to call a template file and do the PHP in that, eg {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/atemplate.phtml'}}

Comment: @WombleGold thanks it is working but i'm not able to get order details to write the conditions

Comment: Can you update your question to show the phtml template code you are using now?

Comment: @Naresh: you can try with {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/atemplate.phtml' order=$order}}. 
Then you can get $order = $this->getOrder(); from your template file.